# How to move dashed stroke along path in PS 2022

Tags: path, adobe-photoshop

I have a dashed line and want another dashed line to align with the gaps and dashes:

[image: example picture]

Even when setting the dash length and gap size perfectly they don't align.

Is there a way to move the dashed line to align along the path?

Comment: Are both shapes the exact same size?

Answer (score 0):

Note: this may not work with complex shapes

Create one shape with no fill, a stroke 3 pixels wide with the desired dash/gap lengths:

[image]

Copy and past this shape, place it exactly above the other, change the colour of the stroke, change the width of the stroke to 1 pixel, change to dash/gap length to three times the values selected previously

[image]

Place both shapes in a layer group

Copy the path of one of the shapes and use it as a vector mask for the group

[image]